MCP1700-3302T current backflow
Here is some weird situation that I observed recently. When I power it with 5 V everything works fine and voltages are accurate.
But, when I try to power it via ST-link V2 (just to program the board) directly to the 3V3 power line ONLY, the 5 V LED glows a little bit after 1 second. Does anyone know why this is happening?


The title says 'MCP1700T-3302T', and the schematic 'MCP1700T-3002E'. Which one is true?

I think the D1 is in good condition, I have tested the D1 with multimeter it shows 0L in opposite direction.
Also I found out that MCP1700T-3302T will cause the D1 to fail the diode test (2.2v).  Which I have no idea why. So far I understand that this chip allows current back feed, and that is the reason I am adding the D1.
